# ClassLoader's getResource() method always return null in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

this method works fine in eclipse,but when i use androidStudio,it return null all the time,even i pass "" to the argument,did anyone got this problem before?

Android-Studio version is 1.5

here is the test code `Log.e("itag",PropertiesConfig.class.getResource("")+"");`
output is null

any advise is appreciated;

Comment: Have you checked in your build folder after building your project if the file is available in the same directory as the class or the relative path you give?

Comment: actually i don't check it ,there's too much dir under build ,i don't know which is the right dir ,but i pass "" to the argument , normally it should return the path of  class's directory,but it return null instead

Comment: How this this ever work in any environment?  You're asking to look for a resource with the name of an empty string!

Comment: when pass an empty string ,it return the class file's parent directory  normally, i have just confirm it in eclipse  ;but here in Android-studio it return null

Answer (score 2):

You can create a folder in your shared test module called `resources` like in the image [image]

Usually useful to put .json file inside

Then in tests you can do:

```
this.javaClass.classLoader!!.getResource("test_data.json").openStream()
```

to get an `InputStream` of the file content to provide to a JSON parser

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It was always null because the Android build system only includes generic resources from a specific folder, not the java source folders.

Answer (score -1):

Why you use ClassLoader?You cann't load a .class file in android.If you had to ,you should transform .class file to .dex file ,and use DexClassLoader instead.

Comment: i'm not purpose to load a class file ,i use it to load .properties file,but why this method always return null? It works fine in java project,and i use this method to load .properties  when i develop android in eclipse , it's also OK! why  it failed in AS, I hava no clue about this;